# Chromeless YouTube Video Player and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, youtube, youtube-api

This implementation of a Chromeless YouTube video player and custom controls doesn't work on Internet Explorer 11.

I obtain infinite errors like:

> "SCRIPT 87: Argument not valid. www-embed-player.js (541,78)

Any idea to fix this? Thanks

LINE: 541

```
Ii.prototype.sendMessage=function(a){this.source&&(a.id=this.sourceId,a=M(a),this.source.postMessage(a,this.origin))};function Ji(){}
```

video-player.js iframe creation

```
var player;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
  ytplayer = new YT.Player('player', {
    videoId: 'uu9J0c97fB0', 
    width: '640',       
    height: '390',        
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,
      showinfo: 0,
      fs: 0
    },
    events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}
```

Webpage: https://github.com/brianyang/YouTube-Video-Player

Comment: You should probably follow up with the creator of that library on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be not run video-demo.html directly from the file system on pc, and instead run it in a local webserver. This is for security only on Internet Explorer. If you run http://localhost/video-demo.html it works.